# Add empty row/page break after group changes using userform radiobuttons

Tags: vba, excel

I searched other questions but sadly, I couldn't find the right answer.

My Userform :
[image]

My Code :

```
Private Sub cancel_button_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ok_button_Click()
If empty_row_radio = True Then
    MsgBox ThisRng.Address
    For i = ThisRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If ThisRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ThisRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            ThisRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
ElseIf page_break_radio_Click = True Then
    Dim j As Long
    For j = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row To 3 Step -1
        If Range("A" & j).Value <> Range("A" & j - 1).Value Then
                ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("A" & j)
        End If
    Next j
    Unload Me
End If
End Sub

Private Sub inputRange()
Dim ThisRng As Excel.Range
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
range_textbox = ThisRng.Address
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call inputRange
End Sub
```

On initialize of user form, I call the `inputRange()` sub for range selection. After that, range address is shown in `textbox`. Then the user selects one of the radio buttons and on click of **OK** button, the respective code runs to insert an empty row or a page break. 
My problems is that, it doesn't pick up the **selection range**, and hence nothing happens.

Any help?

Comment: `Dim ThisRng As Excel.Range` is a local variable to inputRange sub. This king of problems is easy found when using `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @VincentG ya.  variable not defined error. Thankyou for that. But any way to fix the solution?

Comment: Did you look at the answer from @Vityata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a disclaimer, that you should probably never program like this, but follow some of the good practices in VBA, here is something that would work:

1. Delete the line `Dim ThisRng As Excel.Range` from your code.
2. Write exactly that line on the top of the form.

Some examples of good handling of user forms:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154401/handling-dialog-closure-in-a-vba-user-form
- http://www.riptutorial.com/vba/topic/5351/user-forms

Comment: That worked properly. I couldn't believe it was such a simple error. Also, Thankyou for the links. as well as the answer. The first link is difficult for me to understand right now as I have just 20% of VBA knowledge. And, the second link, I'll definitely give it a read.

Comment: @AmanDevrath - you are welcome. The second link used to be official documentation from StackOverflow, but the documentation was disabled.